# HTTP Keep-Alive puzzle with EC2 Linux, Nginx and Chrome

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, linux-networking, google-chrome, keepalive

Please, help to solve HTTP keep-alive problem.
Basically, I have amazon-ami linux (*v2012.09*) on EC2 running nginx (*v1.2.6*).

Chrome (*v25.0.1364.99*) accesses HTTP page normally, then after about 30 seconds connection dropped (unknown why) as monitored on server by `netstat`. After that, if chrome requests  something from server, it can't receive anything and timeouts for about a minute waiting for something on apparently broken connection. After timeout subsequent requests works ok.

Nginx configured with `keepalive_timeout 70s 60s;`

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` shows `7200`

It might be something easy, but googling revealed a lot of similar problems, but not exactly.
(https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27400 read about here http://blog.fastmail.fm/2011/06/28/http-keep-alive-connection-timeouts/).

What answers would be helpful:

- How to alter configuration of server to avoid excessive waiting on dropped connection from Chrome
- What product might content bug or what workaround may be available

Disable keep alive for chrome is kind of last resort solutions: as it defeats the purpose as I want to reduce response latency and have long HTTP connection keep-alive time, at least a minute.
Thanks

Comment: If you run a packet capture on the linux host, do you see the rst being sent at 30 seconds? If not, I would suspect a load balancer or firewall timeout.

Comment: It might not even be your firewall, it could be the client's firewall.

Comment: @DerfK might be, but for this specific case I tend to exclude problem somewhere before EC2 as was reproduced under different networks

Comment: Do a tcpdump. Which side closes the connection? Is an HTTP proxy being used? Does it happen with HTTPS? Does it happen without HTTPS on a different port? Does it happen with different browsers? Does it happen with Chrome on a different machine or OS?

Comment: @mgorven will use your comment as action plan, currently I'm in process of setting up an HTTPS so will get some answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such environment, an HTTPS connection doesn't not get sneakily closed after 30s, so when I put a site completely under HTTPS (which was actually planned), Chrome Keep=Alive problem no longer manifest itself with Keep-Alive for a minute, which is acceptable.

Unfortunately, I had no resources to invest into TCP debugging. So puzzle is not solved completely, per se.

Many thanks for suggestions!